# What is the "*debug* buffer" in Kakoune?

Tags: debugging, kakoune

I'm just starting with the [Kakoune](https://github.com/mawww/kakoune) editor and somehow I was shown the message `error during startup, see *debug* buffer for details` when I loaded a file with `kak`.

I don't know if I'm too stupid to ask this, but I don't know how do I "see *debug* buffer". The `:debug` option seems to be there to write something to the debug buffer, not read it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out that there's a buffer called "*debug*", to visit it you must

```
:buffer *debug*
```

Thanks to @danr on #kakoune @ freenode IRC.

Comment: Feel free to [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) :)